# Output values from servlet page are not updating in rows of JTable - Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, servlets, jtable

Output values from the Servlet page is coming correctly But those values are not updating into the rows of the Java JTable.
The row count has been incrementing in the JTable But not Refreshing(displaying) in the Java GUI.

Adding data into the rows of Table-->

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException 
        {
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try{
        //*****************slno***************************/
        String slno = request.getParameter("slno");
        a = slno;
        System.out.println("Source id--->:  "+demo123.a);
        out.println("<p>slno: " + slno + "</p>");
        //*****************lattitude***************************/
        String lattitude = request.getParameter("lattitude");
        b = lattitude;
        System.out.println("lattitude--->:  "+demo123.b);
        out.println("<p>lattitude: " + lattitude + "</p>");
        //*****************longitude***************************/
        String longitude = request.getParameter("longitude");
        c = longitude;
        System.out.println("longitude--->:  "+ demo123.c);
        out.println("<p>longitude: " + longitude + "</p>");

    ServerGUI.rows=ServerGUI.table.getRowCount();
        System.out.println("row count"+ServerGUI.table.getRowCount());
        ServerGUI.Tmodel.addRow(new Object[]{a,b,c});
        System.out.println( "Row count :" + ((DefaultTableModel)ServerGUI.table.getModel()).getRowCount());
        ServerGUI.table.repaint();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

GUI JTable method in Java GUI program-->

```
table = new JTable();
    Tmodel = new DefaultTableModel(0,0);
    String header[] = new String[]{"SOURCE ID", "LATTITUDE", "LONGITUDE"};
    Tmodel.setColumnIdentifiers(header);
    table.setModel(Tmodel);
```

Comment: 1) `}catch(Exception e){}` This is throwing away useful information. Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()` 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: kk i will correct those try catch blocks....can you please tell me solution for the above JTable rows updation problem

Comment: *"can you please tell me solution for the above JTable rows updation problem"* Can you follow my advice to post an MCVE / SSCCE? Can you copy/paste the output from the stack traces? I have no idea what is going wrong without the latter, and no motivation to look into it closely without the former.

Comment: If the data in the model is not getting painted then it means 1) the model has not been added to the table or 2), the table has not been added to the GUI. Maybe you have two instances of the table one that is an instance variable and once that is a local variable.